# módulo keyboard python: Supress = True/False, pra que serve?

Tags: python

Olá estava testando o módulo "keyboard" no python e não encontrei uma boa explicação nem na documentação do módulo sobre um parâmetro (se eu estiver errado me corrijam) chamado "Supress" em algumas funções do programa, como por exemplo:

add_hotkey(hotkey, callback, args=(), **suppress=False**, timeout=1, trigger_on_release=False)

"`suppress` defines if successful triggers should block the keys from being
sent to other programs." - Essa é a explicação que o HELP do programa dá.

Mas na prática, o que significa isso? Imaginei que era pra impedir que comandos fossem lidos fora do terminal mas não parece que esse é o caso.

Comment: Sim, é bem isso. Com o `suppress=True` o comando lido não será propagado a outros programas. Por que afirma que não parece ser isso?

Comment: Porque quando eu testei isso o comando ainda podia escrever fora do terminal do python. (No caso, com um comando de escrever, obviamente)